# Xamarin.Android Targeting Android 4.4 Throws Error No resource identifier found for attribute touchscreenBlocksFocus in package android

Tags: android, xamarin

Our Xamarin.Android app is targeting Android 4.4 due to hardware constraints.  The initial solution was created targeting API 23 and was downgraded.  The above error is thrown after downgrading.  The code referenced by the error is as follows:

```
    <include layout="@layout/abc_screen_content_include"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        style="?attr/actionBarStyle"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
        android:gravity="top">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
            style="?attr/toolbarStyle"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
            android:id="@+id/action_context_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            style="?attr/actionModeStyle"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
```

This error was replicated after creating a new solution targeting API 19 Android 4.4.
How do I remedy the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit this in Xamarin Forms Project.  Got this lovely:

*"No resource identifier found for attribute **'touchscreenBlocksFocus'** in package 'android' App1.Droid C:\dev\xamarin\dev\HWVFromScratch\App1 App1.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\C6193E5D3119528BCA215B6037E272DE\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml"*

To squarely target KitKat

Go into your Droid project properties

- Set "Compile using Android Version" to "Use Latest Platform"
- Set Minimum Android to Android 4.4( API Level 19 - KitKat )
- Set Target Android version to Android 4.4 ( API Level 19 - KitKat )

Compiled like a champ.  Screenshot of settings below...

[image: KitKat 4.4 Xamarin Forms Droid Project Settings]

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that the Google tool `aapt` which is used to compile resources for your app doesn't know how to handle the `touchscreenBlocksFocus` attribute used somewhere in your resources (or in this case likely in the resources contained in the *Android Support Libraries*).

First it's worth reviewing my blog post explaining the various places API Levels are used in Xamarin.Android apps: http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/

So in this case, your project's ***Target Android Version*** is what Xamarin.Android is passing to `aapt` as the API Level to build resources against.

This means you'll need to set your ***Target Android Version*** to a higher API Level (4.4 won't cut it) which understands the resource attributes you are using.

Of course, just because you change your ***Target Android Version*** doesn't mean you can't still have a lower ***Minimum Android Version*** specified, and your app can then still run on older API Levels.

Finally, it's generally best practice to set your ***Target Framework Version*** and ***Target Android Version*** to use the Latest SDK version available to avoid these types of issues.  Then, set your ***Minimum Android Version*** to a lower API level if you wish.  Of course you'll have to be aware of the API's you are using and that you take appropriate steps to gracefully avoid using API's that aren't available on a given version of Android at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a month, but I would like to try and answer your question with the solution I had.

The problem I ran into was that I attempted to use Xamarin.Forms instead of functions/commands/API from the standard Android libraries.

One of the ways to install Xamarin.Forms is to use nuget - which I did. This however caused all kinds of problems, one of which you are experiencing.

So in order to stop these errors I had to remove several dependencies/references within the Xamarin Project by going to Project -> Edit References -> and on the right hand side of the window removing any Xamarin.XXXXX you might see starting with the obvious Xamarin.Forms and working your way through until you can finally compile your project successfully again.

While this was an answer to my similar issue, if you absolutely have to use Xamarin.XXXXX then this won't fix your issue as you are going to have to use the tools supplied by Android.XXXX.